# storing data through session variables

Tags: java, mysql, session, jakarta-ee

my application permits to the user to do some actions 
I want to memorize his name when he connect then insert it into the database (in order to know who did the action) without forcing him to write

Here is the code of my servlet

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
User userName= new User(name);
request.getSession().setAttribute("user_name", userName);
response.sendRedirect("next.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already stored the attribute in the current session, you can call to the attribute in any servlet you want and store it in a database you use JDBC.

Exemple :
This is my database achitecture :

Table user

```
|id |name      |password|
|01 |John due  |xxxxxxx |
```

Table product

```
|id |name      |price   |
|07 |coca-cola |03      |
```

table transaction

```
|id |user_id | product_id |
```

and in your code you write

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

User user = request.getSession().getAttribute(ATT_USER);
Product product = request.getSession().getAttribute(ATT_PRODUCT);

int userId = user.getId();
int productId = product.getId();

String query = "insert into transaction(user_id,product_id) values (?,?)";

PreparedStatement prep = conn.preparestatement(query);
        try {
            prep = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            prep.setInt(1,userId);
            prep.setInt(2,productId);

            prep.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

then you shall have in your database

```
|id |user_id | product_id |
|01 |01      |07          |
```